# RTK query based on data from another request

Tags: reactjs, redux, rtk-query

I have some rtk query, that query data based on response of another request ( with axios )

```
const { dat } = useGetDataQuery({
  keys // it comes from another request
})

export const someApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'someApi',
  baseQuery,
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getData: builder.query<
      any,
      { keys: string[] }
    >({
      query: (arg) => {
        const { keys } = arg
        return {
          url: '/some_endpoint',
          params: {
            keys,
          },
        }
      },
    }),
  }),
})
```

And in this case data from previous request it's keys.
Is it possible make request inside query and use this data for my query, instead of doing
this request outside and pass data as params?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend it. Theoretically it is possible, using `queryFn`, as you have access to `getState` there - but if that state value would ever change, that wouldn't re-execute your query. It's really best to just put in dynamic values as argument.

Comment: And did you recommend for this part using listener so when the first query is done, it does the second one ?

Comment: Write them after each other and use the `skip` option with the second one while the first one is not finished. You can extract them into a custom hook.