# implement dependend queries using queryFn

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have an api created like this (shortened):

```
const api = createApi({
  …,
  endpoints: b => ({
    getSessionData: …,
    postSessionData: …,

    getTopics: b.query({
      queryFn: : async (arg, queryApi, extraOptions, baseQuery) => {
        // how to do the following:
        const sessionData = await …  // What is recommend to use here?

        return …
      }
    })
  })
})
```

So as I have tried to illustrate in the comments above, I would like to use data from another query within a query. So one query depends on another and I would like to implement it in such a way, that `getTopics` will stay in a loading state until both finished. I have tried something along those lines:

```
const sessionData = await queryApi.dispatch(api.endpoints.getSessionData.select());
```

But that wont wait for the data to be loaded.

What is the recommend way here?

Answer (score 2):

You have plenty ways to do it

### You can do [multiple queries inside a `queryFn`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#performing-multiple-requests-with-a-single-query)

```js
const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '/ ' }),
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getTopics: build.query({
      async queryFn(_arg, _queryApi, _extraOptions, fetchWithBQ) {
        const sessionResult = await fetchWithBQ('/session')
        const topicsResult = await fetchWithBQ(`/topics`)
        return topicsResult.data
          ? { data: topicsResult.data }
          : { error: topicsResult.error }
      },
    }),
  }),
})
```

### You can use [listener middleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware)

If you want to run some logic when a thunk is finish, having a listener can help you.

```js
listenerMiddleware.startListening({
  matcher: api.endpoints.getSession.fulfilled,
  effect: async (action, listenerApi) => {         
    listenerApi.dispatch(api.endpoints.getTopics.initiate())
   }
  },
})
```

### With react

```js
const ComponentStuff = () => {
  const { data: session } = useSessionQuery();
  const { data: topics } = useTopicsQuery(session, { skip: !! session });
}
```

You can use [skip also on the second one to not do it until the first one is finished](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73102546/7618742)

Comment: I really appreciate the Idea of using middleware. But I would need the queries the other way around. Moreover It would be just fine to have `getTopics` keeping on waiting for the session data …

Comment: You mean topics is dependent on session ? Then If it's the case I'll update the answer to be more clear

Comment: yeah, I guess that this wont change anything that related to the problem itself, which is a dependency on queries - it's just the same but the other way around …

Comment: yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom hook that executes those queries after each other, and the second one only if it succeeded:

```js
function useDependentQueries(arg1){
  const first = useFirstQuery(arg1)
  const second  = useSecondQuery(first.isSuccess ? { /* build your argument */ } : skipToken)
  return second
}
```